# How to train CNN on LFW dataset?

Tags: keras, face-recognition, tf.keras, sequential, facial-identification

I want to train a facial recognition CNN from scratch. I can write a Keras Sequential() model following popular architectures and copying their networks.

I wish to use the LFW dataset, however I am confused regarding the technical methodology. Do I have to crop *each* face to a tight-fitting box? That seems impractical, as the dataset has 13000+ faces.

Lastly, I know it's stupid, but all I have to do is preprocess the images (of course), then ***fit the model to these images?*** What's the exact procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very open ended. Before preprocessing and fitting the model, you need to understand Object Detection. Once you understand what object detection you will get answer to your 1st question whether you are required to manually crop every 13000 image. The answer is no. However, you will have to draw bounding boxes around faces and assign label to images if they are not available in the training data.

Your second question is very vague . What do you mean by exact procedure? Is it the steps you need to do or how to do preprocessing and fitting of the model in python/or any other language? There are lots of references available on the internet about how to do preprocessing and model training for every specific problem. There are no universal steps which can be applied to any problem